# Can the server do anything other than close the client connection on a error while streaming HTTP data?

Tags: http, error-handling, streaming

I have a server which reads data from one socket, tweak it, and send it back out on another socket. The main client uses HTTP to get the data. I use streaming in this case because I can just return a 200 and no need for an ETag or a caches (a CDN can take care of that part.)

Instead of the `Size: ...` tag I use:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

My question is, when there is an error, what can I possibly do other than just closing the connection with the client? My concern is that the client may not notice an error in that case.

i.e. the partial data the client is going to receive may look 100% correct because I sent it by *packets* and there is no specific *end packet*.

Note that I'm not in control of the file format being used.